# Unable to schedule a jenkins build using parameters on a slave machine

Tags: jenkins, automation

Trying to schedule a build using parameterised build schedule. The Job type is maven

Comment: try to add some additional information about your job configuration please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Parameterized Scheduler Plugin:**

**Github:** https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin

**Jenkins Plugins:** https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler

After installing the plugin just use the **"Build periodically with parameters"**

[image]

Configure it as you need:

**Example:**

`# every 5 minutes with var1=foo and var2=bar
 H 5 * * * % var1=foo;var2=bar`

**Note that you need to create the parameters in your job first.** This is done in the 'General' configuration section **>** 'This project is parameterized' **>** Add Parameter.

Comment: I did try this, but got to know that its not working for Maven Project, working fine freestyle project